# UIView translation z position in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my app requires an object to be translated according to the user's touch on screen like Tinder. The objects are presented in UITableViewCells inside a UITableView. When I translate an object, the object goes under the top cell and it moves over the bottom cells. Please refer to the screen shots provided. My question is: How can I let the object move over the top cell while translating as well?
[image: Under Top Bar]

[image: Over Bottom Cells]

Answer (score 1):

So, your Z-index is based on the order that views were added to the container.  You should be able to call bringSubviewToFront: on your UITableView and pass in the cell you want to have on top.  Then it should display over both the top and bottom cells.

Answer (score 0):

Okay What I did is that where I'm handling the panning, when the panning begins, I type in

```
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
```

Hence, every cell in use will be automatically brought to the front.